# Extracting words from non unique table rows Tableau 2020.2.6

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I have a list of data in tableau with different total string count and different suffixes for example:

1. SAO JOSE DO RIO PRETO 1
2. SAO JOSE DO RIO PRETO 2
3. SAN LUIS 1
4. BELO HORIZONTE 3
5. RIO DE JANEIRO EDU
6. GOIANIA (Jc-01)
7. RIO DE JANEIRO (JE-09)
8. RIO DE JANEIRO 1 (CFMG)

In tableau 2020.2.6 ... REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, "^([A-Z]+ )*[A-Z]+") does not work.

Thank you in advance for your tips.

Comment: `([A-Z][a-z]+ )+[A-Z][a-z]+` this regex will work

Comment: Hello @AbdessabourMtk, Thank you for the reply but this doesn't do it. This basically grabs the last letter in every line.

Comment: Use `^([A-Z]+(?: +[A-Z]+)*)`

Comment: Hi All, thank you for the help. @WiktorStribiżew, your solution got me on the right path. Since I only wanted city name so, I didn't want "EDU" selected as well, this modified version of your solution worked ... ^([A-Z]+(?: +[A-Z]+)* (?:^EDU)?)

Comment: That's a corrupt pattern. `'^([A-Z]+(?: +[A-Z]+)* (?:^EDU)?)'` is identical to `'^([A-Z]+(?: +[A-Z]+)* )'`

Answer (score -1):

the following regular expression will match the city [names](https://regex101.com/r/rNl4DK/1)

```
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]+ )*[A-Z][a-z]+
```

use it with `REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, "^(?:[A-Z][a-z]+ )*[A-Z][a-z]+")`

Comment: Hello, @AbdessabourMtK ... I am using this REGEXP_EXTRACT([string], '([A-Z]+ )*[A-Z]+'), since the city are in all CAP's. My apologies for omission. For one word cities i get "null and for multi word cities it grabs the second word in the string.

Comment: @sycythe_j can you update the question with accurate examples, also the null and the selecting of the second word is due to the way `REGEXP_EXTRACT` work. I'll look into the documentation and try to come up with a solution.

Comment: @sycythe_j try the new answer.